# AWS Lambda + API Gateway response non-utf8 CSV

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, utf-8, aws-api-gateway

Requirement:

- Use AWS Lambda + API Gateway
- Function language: Python
- Convert a text from UTF-8 to Shift_JIS (such as: 武蔵野冷蔵名古屋)
- Response with csv format (application/csv)

Issue:

- I'm using `response = codecs.encode(inputString, 'SHIFT_JIS', errors='ignore')` with inputString something like `武蔵野冷蔵名古屋`: encode input string with shift_jis
- And I return `response` to user. But facing error `Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys: {'requestId', 'errorMessage', 'stackTrace', 'errorType'} in {'errorMessage': "Unable to marshal response: 'utf-8' codec can't decode  byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte"`.

Seem that API Gateway just support UTF-8 for text.

My concern is how to response non UTF-8 text when combine Lambda + API Gateway.

- I'm checking the guide [setup Binary data with API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-binary-data-lambda/) but not work now
- I don't want to base64.encode it and decode later at client side.

Any help for this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God!

I was guided to solve this issue.

Just base64 encode the string_after_encode_to_shift_jis.

```
return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-Type': f'application/csv; charset=shift_jis'
            },
            'body': base64.b64encode(data.encode(enc)).decode('utf-8'),
            'isBase64Encoded': True
        }
```